# Increase storage on running EC2 using EBS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a instance running on EC2 with default storage of 8GB. I also have mysql running on that instance which is taking most of the storage on the instance.

I have already created another volume mounted on /vol1

Is there a way the when mysql run out of storage it start using the new volume or another way to join them together.

I can stop the **mysql** if i have to, to resize.

Comment: the terms you are using are not clear. when you say memory do you mean disk space? can you stop the instance to just resize the volume? can you stop mysql to move the data files? it's not very clear what you are asking. maybe edit the question a bit to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can shift your database to Amazon RDS which will solve your problem of disk overflowing because of database growth.

RDS will scale up as required by your mysql database

Follow the below link to migrate mysql to RDS:

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/